# Can i use dataflow import to update products

Tags: magento2, product, magento-1, import, csv

I am really sorry for asking this. I feel like this is a stupid question, but honestly I have googled until the term googling has lost all meaning.

I just want to do a bulk update of product information, I do not want to add or import new products, just update the information for existing products. But all I seem to be able to find on google is articles referring to importing products into Magento. Perhaps my google-fu is failing me, and if this is the case I apologize, but I would be grateful if someone can just answer this really simple question.

I have a CSV file with updated product information.

I want to use this file to update the existing products in Magento 1.9.x.

Can this be done with importing?

Or will I have to build a script that reads the CSV file and manually updates each product?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the steps I follow when running updates through Dataflow:

- Export all products via 'Export All Products' Dataflow profile. `System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow - Profiles -> 'Export All Products' -> Run Profile -> Run Profile in Popup`
- Edit the exported file, updating the information you require (The exported file location by default is 'var/export/' from your magento installation directory) and save.
- Locate the 'Import All Products' data profile (same location as Export all products).
- View the 'Upload file' tab, upload your new CSV containing updated information and hit 'Save and continue edit'.
- Then Select file from 'Run profile Tab' and Run profile in Popup.
- Enjoy the incredibly slow import!

These are the steps i have followed many times so i'm confident they will work for you.

Let me know if you would like me to make the steps above more in-depth.

Comment: No Problem, i forgot to add that i usually remove the product rows i dont want to update from the CSV as this speeds it up!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did it as a very good experience.
If you imported the product before, the "sku" is necessary for product data update.
To update an attribute for example "description", you can do as Isay.

1. create an import dataFlow profile with two attribute that added from
   " Field Mapping" section of import profile.

[image: import profile]

1. create a .css file with two data field that separated by ",". Assign
   this file as import file for import profile.
2. Run the import profile.
3. check description in product management.
4. will see a successful experience.